# Keyboard and mouse stopped working at Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Managed to load up Ubuntu 13.10 perfectly, then from nowhere when I start the computer, shortly before it hits the home screen all lights disappear from mouse and keyboard.
Keyboard works fine if I access the setup menu

Very new to linux and Ubuntu, so please assume minimal knowledge :)

Comment: Give more information like model of mouse and keyboard, if they worked in any other OS.What you have tried doing till now and what happened or didn't happen.Generally, a google/bing/yahoo search with the text `<model name> not working Ubuntu` should give you your answer.If it doesn't, we are there to help!

Comment: Hi Aditya,  thanks for your response.  I have a Microsoft Wired desktop 600 keyboard and mouse. (which seems to throw up a decent tresponse on google for not working),  I have tried an alternative but i get the same issue.    The problem is that it has previously worked... its just as soon as it hits the "Ubuntu Desktop" so the lights go out.

Comment: There's one solution, first remove the keyboard and mouse.Then reboot Ubuntu.after it's rebooted, connect the devices one by one.Ubuntu should recognise new device and search for drivers.install them and maybe reboot again.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either.  I was hoping to reinstall the cd rom, but even when I get to the recovery menu the keyboard and mouse stop working.  They seem to work fine only in the GNU Grub screen and the setup screen.     If i let Ubuntu 13.10 load up i eventually see a pop up that says.  "data files for some packages could not be downloaded" - refers to "flashplugin-installer"   (ps i do really appreciate the help with this)

Comment: The `flashplugin-installer` can't be related to keyboard problems.BTW you can remove and reinstall `flashplugin-installer` to fix the error.Do you have some reserve keyboard? or can you get one for some time from a friend/relative? The latest kernel should fix your problem.

Comment: I have tried a different mouse and keyboard, and the USB ports for these, but every time it gets to a certain point the lights on mouse & keyboard go ahead and there is no response.  The last part i get to is the GNU Grub screen, which give me the choice of  "ubuntu ; advanced options for ubuntu; memory test (memtest86+) ; or Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115299) "  i can access the command line in grub - but is this the right route to re-install ubuntu ?..  if i choice recovery options the mouse & keyboard go dead again!

Comment: unfortunately **altf-f1** doesn't do anything - all the lights have disappeared from the keyboard on anything past the setup screen.  Also for the questions on the side bar (or other related) it seems they are not quite identical as they have sporadic access... mine seems to be the same issue every time.   I've tried to looking for away to uninstall ubuntu but it seems like i have to load it up first - any other thoughts on where to go from here?

Comment: Sorry. It should be ctrl +alt +f1

Comment: no good either i'm afraid... on another note, i can get the lights on the mouse to register if i plug it in after booting..but there is no cursor on the screen, or a reaction to left / right clicks.